# Swagger recursive reference (with Intellij Idea plugin)

Tags: intellij-idea, swagger, openapi

I have Swagger plugin and Node.yaml json schema, which is referenced in openapi 3.0 spec:

```yaml
description: Node that holds values.
type: object
properties:
  id: { type: string }
  parent:
    $ref: 'Node.yaml'
    description: Parent node.
```

And this is failing with StackOverflowError, when I try to preview in browser

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:287)
...
```

First, I don't know is this problem with plugin, or with spec. Second, how can I bypass this? I don't want to set parent's type to arbitrary object in json schema, because I want to have validation.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if I alter two things:

1. Move Node json schema in components of openapi spec;
2. Instead of directly referencing to Node in parent, put reference in `allOf` block

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Node:
      description: Node that holds value.
      type: object
      properties:
        id: { type: string }
        parent:
          description: Parent node.
          allOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Node'
```

I saw something similar on github in issues. But it's not obvious. I don't like this workaround, because I need really mess my project structure, after I already created a bunch of json schemas.

### Second way

Specifically, if you want to extract schema in a separate file, this will also work:

```yaml
# In openapi spec
components:
  schemas:
    Node:
      $ref: Node.yaml
```

```yaml
# In Node.yaml
description: Node that holds value.
type: object
properties:
  id: { type: string }
  parent:
    description: Parent node.
    $ref: '#/' # even doesn't need allOf block
```

P.S. I posted answer, but I am still waiting for a good answer)